# UniDac MySQL transaction issue

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am using Delphi, UniDac and MySQL.

I have a table `Invoices` and one other `InvoiceItems`.
Table `Invoices` holds the basic information such as date, number, customerid etc
Table `InvoiceItems` holds the items that are attached to the invoice productid, price etc

When user clicks to add a new Invoice
`Invoices.Insert`;

He can start adding the details. But when he wants to add items, with the current design I have he has to save the record first, obtain the InvoiceId and then start adding records to InvoiceItems with the corresponding InvoiceID.

Is there anyway to do it without saving the record first? As I can see it can be done with transactions but I am not sure how to design this.

Please note that the software is multi-user, two users can insert an invoice at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: The canonical way to do this is to save the invoice first, get the invoiceid then store the lines, inserting the invoiceid as a foreign key in each tuple (line). What's wrong with this? This design helps with multi-user software, as each invoice will get a separate invoiceid. There is no need for transactions here. A transaction would be needed if you are posting a journal entry in which there are at least two rows (one debit, one credit) which have to be posted together, but that's not the case here.

Comment: And how the invoice items will be edited? They need a InvoiceID. And what happend if user wants to cancel inserting. It has to be cancaled and all items added removed? That's not a good way

Comment: As both you and I wrote, invoice items receive the InvoiceID as a foreign key; each line also has its own primary key. If you want to cancel an invoice which has yet to be made final, then of course you would have to delete the items then delete the invoice (or mark it as deleted). But you shouldn't be able to do anything with an invoice that has already been finalised or printed.